# Android Studio: Positioning buttons created in a loop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-button, dynamically-generated

I am creating buttons dynamically using a loop in Android Studio. However these buttons are overlapping each-other. Currently I have set the loop to run a certain number of times, eventually I will be using a number from a database which could vary. I am trying to set these buttons so that no matter the number of buttons, they are always centered horizontally. The toast was included as I couldn't see if more than one button was created as they are all on top of each other.

```
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.space_layout);


    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++ ){
        Button myButton = new Button(this);// initialization of new button
        myButton.setText("");
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(myButton);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button Created" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I keep asking myself why do people like to build their UI programmatically...

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you using a _RelativeLayout_ params when you're inside a _LinearLayout_ ?

Comment: How do you want it to look when you have a small number / a big number of buttons ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if this is what you're looking for :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int number = 5; // number of buttons
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.space_layout);
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            myButton.setText("btn " + i);
            layout.addView(myButton);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/space_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```